# How can I describe a particular point along the width of an object?

Tags: single-word-requests

A cube might be 10 meters high, 10 meters deep and 10 meters wide. I can describe a point in that cube as being at a height of 2 meters, and at a depth of 3 meters, but it sounds wrong to say that my point is at a "width" of 4 meters.

Is there a single word to describe how far into the cube my point is along the "width" direction?

Comment: X-axis, Y-axis, Z-axis.

Comment: "Two meters from the bottom, three from the front, and four from the left" (or 'right', you didn't specify)

Comment: 2m high, 3m *across* and 2 back...

Answer (score 1):

Given *height* and *depth*, ***length*** sounds better than *width* to me.

You could add the ***-wise*** suffix on all the terms to make them positional in nature rather than dimensional.

However, if you choose more positional words to begin with, I think ***over*** fairs better:

> My point is 2 *up*, 3 *back*, and 4 ***over***.

In any case, you would need to clarify whether it is over from the left or right for the sake of precision.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be far more clear to describe it mathematically.

A 10 meter cube is aligned with a Cartesian coordinate system with corners at (0,0,0) and (10,10,10).  My point is at (4,3,2).

Comment: The OP is asking how to say it in everyday English, so while your answer is good engineering advice, it doesn't answer how to say it informally.

Comment: You're right, I should have stated that I couldn't think of an easy way to say it without mathematics.  Maybe "4 meters from the left face"?  I'm an engineer and MY everyday English would be to say it as in my original answer.

Comment: The problem with everyday English is that it is inadequate to say this kind of thing tersely without ambiguity.  For example, the OP might think that "depth of 3 meters" is clear, but I would have interpreted it to mean "3 meters" from the top surface.  Apparently that is not the intent because there is also a height specified.

Comment: @Mitch - The OP is asking how to say something mathematical without using math.

Answer (score 0):

If you designate the corners of the cube as: *a, b, c, d,* and the sides as: *A, B, C, D,* the location will be easier to pinpoint. Ex:

"Measuring along side (A), from corner (a) to corner (b), the point is 2 meters high, and three meters deep, at the four meter mark.

Comment: Hmm... I was working from the 'base'.

Comment: Your description requires a picture, then, or a lot more words.